# Drawing a 16 * 16 Textview grid

Tags: android

I am creating a simple word puzzle where i will need to draw a 16 *16 grid of textviews.

My two options are using a layout or creating one programmatically. I assume the one created programmatically will be very slow while the one created using an xml will be tricky to create. What other options do i have.

If anyone has created one before, can you share your experiences ? The grid will be very much alike a cross word puzzle grid.

Kind Regards,

Comment: you can draw with the help of canvas. it will easy to handle.

Comment: I would go for the canvas too. Writing the touch handler is trivial and you have full control over styling the text. It's faster too.

Comment: The problem with XML is that you'll need one layout for each different crossword.  If you have 50 crosswords in your app, then you need 50 XML layouts.  I did a crossword game in the past - and creating layouts on the fly in the code was quick enough for me.

Comment: how slow is it ? 16*16 edittexts are alot of objects in memory ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an XML layout. You can create a reusable style so the XML will be less verbose. It won't be nearly as complicated as the Canvas route because each TextBox will be its own view, with its own handlers. With a Canvas, you would have to manage drawing and detecting change based on coordinates.